# Need to Align All Line Normals to Global Direction in ANSYS APDL

Tags: ansys, meshing, ansys-apdl

I am using beam elements to mesh lines with "pre-meshed" shell areas. Problem is that the line normals are arbitrarily assigned to the lines resulting beam cross sections switched at line junctions. For instance, all lines in X-direction have their respective line normals flipped to arbitrary direction at line junction.

I want to align **all selected lines** along X-axis to be aligned in same direction, say, positive X axis

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting direction vectors for Lines in ANSYS APDL](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58455/setting-direction-vectors-for-lines-in-ansys-apdl)

Comment: @Öskå But leverse command reverses all the lines and the issue is still not resolved.