# Setting direction vectors for Lines in ANSYS APDL

Tags: structural-engineering, beam, ansys, meshing, ansys-apdl

I am using beam elements to mesh lines with "pre-meshed" shell areas. Problem is that the ANSYS sets Line **Direction vectors** on its own.

This results in Cross sections assignment **flipped** from line to line.

For instance, all lines in X-direction have their respective line vectors flipped to arbitrary direction at line junction.

I want to align all selected lines along X-axis to be aligned in same direction, say, positive X axis

Thanks

Comment: If it's not too late, try the `lreverse` command, that you can locate in the Preprocessor, Modeling, Move/Modify, Reverse Normals.

Comment: @Öskå But ""leverse"" command reverses all the lines and the issue is not resolved.

Comment: Do you have a small working example of your issue that we could replicate?